# Python Requests Library timing out under Linux

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to use the requests.py library for calls to a rest web service. I wrote a quick prototype for my usage under windows and everything worked fine, but when I attempted to run the same prototype under linux I get a "requests.exceptions.Timeout: Request timed out" error. Does anyone know why this might be happening? If I try to use the library to access a non https url it works fine under both windows and linux.

```
import requests

url = 'https://path.to.rest/svc/?options'
r = requests.get(url, auth=('uid','passwd'), verify=False)
print(r.content)
```

I did notice that if I leave off the verify=False parameter from the get call, I get a different exception, namely "requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available". This appears to be a possible underlying cause, though I dont know why they would change the errorcode, but I cant find any reference to an ssl module and I verified that certifi was installed. Interestingly, if I leave off the verify parameter in windows I get a different exception, "requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

EDIT:

Tracebacks for all cases/scenarios mentioned

Full code as shown above:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "testRequests.py", line 15, in <module>
        r = requests.get(url, auth=('uid','passwd'), verify=False)
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/api.py", line 52, in get
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/api.py", line 40, in request
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/sessions.py", line 208, in request
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/models.py", line 586, in send
requests.exceptions.Timeout: Request timed out
```

Code as shown above minus the "verify=False" paramter:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "testRequests.py", line 15, in <module>
        r = requests.get(url, auth=('uid','passwd'))
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/api.py", line 52, in get
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/api.py", line 40, in request
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/sessions.py", line 208, in request
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/requests/models.py", line 584, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available
```

Code as show above minus the "verify=False" parameter and run under windows:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "testRequests.py", line 59, in <module>
        r = requests.get(url, auth=('uid','passwd'))
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 52, in get
        return request('get', url, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 40, in request
        return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 208, in request
        r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 584, in send
        raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: What happens when you run `import ssl; from ssl import socket` in the same Python environment where you get `requests.exceptions.Timeout: Request timed out` error?

Comment: I have added the tracebacks, my apologies for leaving them out. I have also attempted the import commands you mention and get a ImportError: No module named _ssl, however if I run that under my windows environment it imports fine, that appears to be my problem. The only module on pypi for ssl is one to give the ssl functionality to older versions of python implying 2.7 should have it. Any idea why it wont import? Do I need to install ssl on the server in question (I have not checked to see if it is already installed or not)?

Comment: Can you try this:
`import ssl; ssl.get_server_certificate(('google.com',443))` ? and see what happens.

Comment: the import ssl command fails. Also, this is being developed and run on a private network so I do not have any external connectivity to services like google.

Comment: ssl is part of CPython... you may need to recompile python with openssl support. (I once compiled Python 2.7 on mac without openssl installed and had this very similar problem). Can't help you with Windows but for Linux use the package manager (`yum` or `apt-get`) Remove it, install openssl and install it (compile it if you can).

Comment: ok I will try that. Thanks :-) oh and everything in windows works fine. I was only mentioning that as a point of comparison in trying to determine why one worked but not the other.

Comment: What does `sys.version` show?

Comment: Thanks lukecampbell. I edited the appropriate file and recompiled and that appears to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the matter but it looks like the certificate from the server can't be verified correctly. I don't know how Python and ssl handles certificate verification but the first option is to try ignoring the exception, or maybe change `https` to `http` in an attempt to see if the web-service allows non-secure service calls.

If the issue is revolving around an import error for `ssl`, the module is part of CPython and you may need to ensure that the Python interpreter is compiled with SSL support (from openssl). Look into removing the package for python (be careful) and compiling it with openssl support, personally I would strongly advise you looking into a virtualenv before removing anything, compiling Python is not too difficult and it would give you a finer grain of control for what you aim to do.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The server does not allow non-secure connections I have already asked that question, and the certificate verification is being ignored by the "verify=False" parameter, and the error persists.

Comment: Can you get any certificates from the server in Python?  `import ssl; ssl.get_server_certificate(('google.com',443))` You can replace google.com with the web service hostname.

Comment: @lukecampbell Sorry for necroposting, but I have a similar issue and `import ssl; ssl.get_server_certificate(('google.com',443))` just hangs for me – do you have any ideas what to do next to troubleshoot this?